# SQL Server - simple select and conversion between int and string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple select statement like this:

```
SELECT [dok__Dokument].[dok_Id], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_WartUsNetto], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_WartUsBrutto], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_WartTwNetto], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_WartTwBrutto], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_WartNetto], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_WartVat], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_WartBrutto], 
       [dok__Dokument].[dok_KwWartosc] 
  FROM [dok__Dokument] 
 WHERE [dok_NrPelnyOryg] = 2753 
   AND [dok_PlatnikId] = 174 
   AND [dok_OdbiorcaId] = 174 
   AND [dok_PlatnikAdreshId] = 625 
   AND [dok_OdbiorcaAdreshId] = 624
```

Column `dok_NrPelnyOryg` is of type varchar(30), and not null.

The table contained both integer and string values in this column and this select statement was fired millions of times.

However recently this started crashing with message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'garbi czerwiec B' to data type int.

Little explanation: the table contains multiple "document" records and the mentioned column contains document original number (which comes from multiple different sources).

I know I can fix this by adding '' around the the number, but I'm rather looking for an explanation why this used to work and while not changing anything now it crashes.

Comment: Obviously the error message says it all. If `dok_NrPelnyOryg` is of type `varchar` why don't you query it as it? `dok_NrPelnyOryg = '2753'`. The automatic conversion simply fails because he can't convert  your value into a number.

Comment: To be fair, the question wasn't how to fix it, it was more about why it worked for some time and then stopped working.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - that's the point. I know how to fix it and I wrote about it.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that a plan change (due to changed statistics, recompile etc) led to this data being evaluated earlier (full scan for example), or that this particular data was not in the table previously (maybe before this started happening, there wasn't bad data in there). If it is supposed to be a number, then make it a numeric column. If it needs to allow strings as well, then stop treating it like a number. If you properly parameterize your statements and always pass a varchar you shouldn't need to worry about whether the value is enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: The query is parametrized, those values are example only. It is fired by using SqlCommand object and ExecuteReader(). While loop with reader.Read() executes multiple times and then it crashes on this one. It's been working for more than half a year this way.

Comment: If it's parameterized then how can you fix it by putting single quotes around it? I think perhaps we have a different idea of what parameterized means. You should be able to pass a parameter to your query from C# without having to worry about technical details like string delimiters.

Comment: No, I think we have the same idea what parametrized means :) I meant that I could fix it like this while executing it from management studio. I've checked now that in code the parameter is of type System.Data.DbType.Int32 which is plain wrong. Fixing this in code isn't easy, because I get all the values as object (not concrete types) SqlParameter as I found out can't handle this itself even if the real type under object is System.String.

Comment: If you use a stored procedure, you should be able to get the parameter types right without any magic voodoo. :-)

Comment: I don't think I can fix it this way. The software synchronizes two databases (accounting and e-commerce) and generates queries on the fly based on xml configuration file. Introducing stored procedures would be a major step that would require many days to implement properly. (eg. configuration file sometimes changes, that should trigger updating stored procedures)

Comment: So where does it magically derive the assumption that this column/parameter should be Int32? That must be coming from somewhere.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to pin down right now. MSDN says about SqlParameter(string, object): "When you specify an Object in the value parameter, the SqlDbType is inferred from the Microsoft .NET Framework type of the Object." This would mean that int has to appear somewhere earlier.. Anyway the solution that I'll probably implement would be to add optional type parameter to the column description in the configuration file and this will result in setting an explicit DbType in SqlParameter. Is this very dirty hack?

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question and tag it under .Net / C# what have you. I know how all the SQL Server folks will insist you fix this, but I think the .Net folks will have more useful suggestions for you.

Comment: I think I found an answer to the question why it worked and now doesn't. The document that it fails on is from the store owner who, in contrast to other customers, has other documents linked to him (containing strings in that field). Sql server while executing the query chose to apply other conditions first - that's why when it came to this one implicit cast always worked.. At least for usual customers.

Answer (score 1):

All those equality comparison operations are subject to the [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) rules of SQL Server:

> When an operator combines two
>   expressions of different data types,
>   the rules for data type precedence
>   specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the
>   data type with the higher precedence.

Since character types have lower precedence than int types, the query is basically the same as:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM [dok__Dokument] 
 WHERE cast([dok_NrPelnyOryg] as int) = 2753
  ...
```

This has two effects:

- it makes all indexes on columns involved in the WHERE clause useless
- it can cause conversion errors.

You're not the first to have this problem, in fact several CSS cases I faced had me eventually write an article about this: [On SQL Server boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/).

The correct solution to your problem is that *if the field value is numeric then the column type should be numeric*. since you say that the data come from a 3<sup>rd</sup> party application you cannot change, the best solution is to abandon the vendor of this application and pick one that knows what is doing. Short of that, you need to search for character types on character columns:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM [dok__Dokument] 
 WHERE [dok_NrPelnyOryg] = '2753'
  ...
```

In .Net managed ADO.Net parlance this means you use a SqlCommand like follows:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (@"    SELECT ...
      FROM [dok__Dokument] 
     WHERE [dok_NrPelnyOryg] = @nrPelnyOryg
      ... ");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nrPelnyOryg", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = "2754";
...
```

Just make sure you don't fall into he easy trap of passing in a NVARCHAR parameter (Unicode) for comparing with a VARCHAR column, since the same data type precendence rules quoted before will coerce the comparison to occur on the NVARCHAR type, thus rendering indexes, again, useless. the easiest way to fall for this trap is to use the dredded [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) and pass in a string value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll implement the query the way you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your query stopped working because someone inserted the text string in to the field you are querying using `INT`. Up until that time it was possible to implicitly convert the data but now that's no longer the case.

I'd go check your data and, more importantly, the model; as Aaron said do you need to allow strings in that field? If not, change the data type to prevent this happening in the future.

Comment: This field is from accounting software database and I can't change it. What is more I don't want to change it, because it contains either strings and integers (as I wrote those values come from different sources). Strings used to be there right from the beginning, because purchase invoices are stored there too (which are numbered according to many different schemas like 22/FV/2011 and so on)

Comment: In that case, as Aaron said, it's probably because the data has changed and is being evaluated in a different way to before. If all the string data was excluded earlier in the query then the implicit conversion is not a problem. It seems that the string data is now making it further down the pipeline and the conversion fails. I know you are not asking how to fix the problem but to write code which uses an implicit conversion, and hope that it will work forever, seems a little optimistic :)